# Cast a member function of a child class to a parent class

Tags: c++, casting, protocols

Im making a protocol using tcp sockets for a game network, and I would like to abstract my packet handler.
Here's my code:

```
class AbstractPacketHandler;
using handler_t = void (AbstractPacketHandler::*)(NetworkClient &, NetworkMessage &);
using handlers_t = std::unordered_map<int32_t, handler_t>;

class AbstractPacketHandler {
public:
    void parse_packet(NetworkClient &client, NetworkMessage &msg);

protected:
    virtual void init(handlers_t &handlers) = 0;

private:
    AbstractPacketHandler() = default;
    handlers_t _handlers;
};
```

And below an implementation `class ServerHandler: public AbstractPacketHandler`

```
void ServerHandler::init(handlers_t &handlers) {
    handlers[HelloConnectMessage::PROTOCOL_ID] = reinterpret_cast<handler_t>(&ServerHandler::onHello));
}

void ServerHandler::onHello(NetworkClient &, HelloConnectMessage &msg) {
    printf("deserialized hellomsg: %d\n", msg.getHelloVar());
}
```

This compiles but I'm not pretty sure that it's working at runtime.  The problem comes from the fact that I try to `reinterpret_cast` to a pointer of member function of the parent class `AbstractPacketHandler`
Indeed, `using handler_t = void (AbstractPacketHandler::*)(NetworkClient &, NetworkMessage &);` is a pointer of a member function pointing to `AbstractPacketHandler` member functions.
Since `onHello` is a function of my child class `ServerHandler`, i think it can't find the function at runtime.

Am I wrong? And how could I solve it to keep my abstraction?

EDIT

from comments, i try a static-cast to see if the code is supposed to work with it, i get the compilation error:

> error: invalid static_cast from type `void
>   (ServerHandler::*)(NetworkClient&, HelloConnectMessage&)’` to type
>   ‘handler_t {aka `void (AbstractPacketHandler::*)(NetworkClient&,
>   NetworkMessage&)`}

Comment: 'but I'm not pretty sure that it's working at runtime.' Can you be more specific? Is it crashing? Are the contents of the printf not being output? How do you call the handlers?

Comment: I can't test it since I dont have finished my network implementation, I need more time and I don't waste my time working on something not working you know?

Comment: I wanna be sure that I'm not doing wrong things :/

Comment: If you are using reinterpret_cast(), you can be pretty sure you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Ye that's what I though, but I'm not really casting a derived to base class, im casting member functions, that's not the same and it can't compile without a cast

Comment: Rule of thumb for this kind of situation: if static_cast<> causes a compile error, you shouldn't do that. The fact you need reinterpret_cast<> is a strong sign that it's not legal. Edit: Neil! (shakes my fist)

Comment: edited with static cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "works"  only because, in this specific case, `ServerHandler` shares its address with its own internal instance of `AbstractPacketHandler`, so when the handler is invoked with a AbstractPacketHandler `this` pointer, it gets effectively reinterpret_casted as a ServerHandler, which just happens to line up correctly (lucky you).

However, this only works as long as no multiple inheritance is involved. If you had the following, all hell would break loose:

```
class ServerHandler: public Something, public AbstractPacketHandler {};
```

> And how could I solve it to keep my abstraction?

Your best bet is to use `std::function<>` for your handler, like so:

```
using handler_t = std::function<void(NetworkClient &, NetworkMessage &)>;
...

void ServerHandler::init(handlers_t &handlers) {
    handlers[HelloConnectMessage::PROTOCOL_ID] = 
        [this](NetworkClient& a, NetworkMessage& b) {onHello(a, b);};
}
```

This does add an additional layer of indirection, but it's much nicer (you can even get rid of inheritance altogether with this model!)

Comment: I see, how to fix it with multiple ihnerence?

Comment: It would be better to just fix the control flow to not be really strange.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using a pointer to member function. These are one of the worst ideas that C++ ever had and should basically never be used. Use a `std::function<void(NetworkClient&, NetworkMessage&)>`.

Really, it looks to me like the control here is just weird. All you're doing is a) parsing a packet and b) calling a function. The classes and inheritance seem redundant. Why not make `parse_packet` a free function that returns the int32_t you're keying on, then the caller can just invoke the appropriate function directly? In that case it's trivial to make it work even without any indirection even if you want to keep the notion of an abstract handler class (which I would recommend dropping as it has no value). E.G.

```
int32_t parse_packet(NetworkClient &client, NetworkMessage &msg);
class AbstractPacketHandler {
public:
    virtual void on_packet(NetworkClient &client, NetworkMessage &msg);
};
class ServerHandler : AbstractPacketHandler {
    void on_packet(NetworkClient& client, NetworkMessage& msg) override {
        switch(parse_packet(client, msg)) {
        case HelloConnectMessage::PROTOCOL_ID:
            printf("deserialized hellomsg: %d\n", msg.getHelloVar());
            break;
        // More cases
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: The fact that OP isn't making a virtual function for each message type kind of implies he doesn't have an exaustive list to work with, so the switch case is probably not going to work for him.

Comment: I thought about that, but, the way the API is written with the init() function implies that it is actually fixed at initialisation time. I mean, he can still invoke some kind of dynamic map of functions from within on_packet if he really wants to.